# Filtering empty strings from a string containing emojis using spread syntax

Tags: javascript, emoji, spread-syntax

I'm trying to stay hip, so I've been playing with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and emojis. I noticed that when I want to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) empty strings (`''`) out the resulting "spread-ed" array, the empty strings are not being removed. Why is that?

```js
console.log([...'︎']);                 // ['︎', '']
console.log([...'︎'].filter(String));  // ['︎', '']
console.log(['︎', ''].filter(String)); // ['︎']
```

Comment: alert( '' == 0 ); they count as 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is in your string an invisible character, which is a [variation selector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_Selectors_(Unicode_block)). You can see this if you print the character codes:

```js
console.log([...'︎'].map(s => s.charCodeAt(0)));
```

If your goal is to remove that particular [variation selector 15](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fe0e/index.htm), then you could just use a `replace`:

```
s.replace(/\ufe0e/g, '')
```

Note how the emoji is slightly different in the output of the third statement you have. This is the effect of that variation selector, which you take away from the first character in the first two statements. Although that special character does not print anything on itself, and shows as an empty string when isolated, it really is not empty, and so `filter` will not exclude it.

Emoji characters themselves lie outside the single word UTF-16 range, and so they occupy two words.

When you split such a single-character string with `split`, you get two separate characters (a historic oddity of JavaScript), which represent the UTF encoding. If your goal is to count emojis (and other high-range characters) in your string, you could use this code:

```
console.log(s.split('').length - [...s].length);
```

Comment: Was just going to post the same. The character code returned for the "blank character" is actually  `65038`, which I'm seeing identified as  [Unicode Character 'VARIATION SELECTOR-15' (U+FE0E)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fe0e/index.htm).

Comment: Yuck, I hate emojis. So I'll probably need to do something like this then: `[...'︎'].filter(function(n) { return n && n.charCodeAt(0) != 65038; })`

Comment: Depends on what you want to do? You want to translate the emoji to something?

Comment: Well I'm just messing around with this, but effectively I want to remove the "empty" strings. So I guess I can just filter by the empty string and whatever charcode 65038 is.

Comment: @budi But are you not creating that problem only because you're using the spread operator? It seems the simplest solution here would be to simply *not* use the spread operator. That being said, if you were to use the code you commented above, you could shorten it as such: `[...'︎'].filter(n => n && n.charCodeAt(0) != 65038)`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to also note, I originally wanted to count the number of emojis in a string. The more I look that this, the more I realize this will become a huge task to pursue on a Friday afternoon... here's an interesting article about it: http://blog.jonnew.com/posts/poo-dot-length-equals-two

Comment: You could (roughly) count emojis in a string `s` with `console.log(s.split('').length - [...s].length);`

Comment: I must come back to what you said about filtering out 65038: indeed that would be correct if you want to get rid of such variation selectors. Note that there are several characters with such behaviour, so you might need to filter also for some other codes.

Comment: Yup thought about that too after I posted that. It would help if there were some standard "filter" to handle this, however this goes out of scope of my original question. Emojis man...